# Writing index item with `\!

Tags: indexing

For some reason, I want to write an index item with `` `\! `` in it (Not `` `! `` since the index items are written by a special macro).

But `!` is a special character of `makeindex`, I could not simply write `` \index{Foo `\! Bar} ``. `` \index{Foo `\"! Bar} `` is also wrong, since `makeindex` doesn't change `\"`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also `\` needs to be quoted. Since it is not clear, if the backslash should appear as backslash, or if `\!` should add negative space (in math mode), the example contains both variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Foobar
\index{Foo `$"\"!$ Bar}
\index{Foo `\textbackslash"! Bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Raw `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{Foo `$"\"!$ Bar}{1}
\indexentry{Foo `\textbackslash"! Bar}{1}
```

Index `.ind` file after running makeindex:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item Foo `$\!$ Bar, 1
  \item Foo `\textbackslash! Bar, 1

\end{theindex}
```

> [image: Result]